# preg_match_all for Unknown Sets of 3 Integers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all, but I have a problem I am not sure can be solved using this method. The following line is part of what I am retrieving:

XXC033-101-143-147-175-142115-

The sets of numbers (033-101-143, etc) are what I want to refer to. However, the number of sets (always containing three integers) is unknown and can range anywhere from 1 to 10. If I knew there would always only be 2 sets, I would have the following:

```
if (preg_match_all('#([A-Z]{2}C)([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{6})#', $wwalist, $matches))

...rest of code...
```

Is there anyway to do this when I have no way of knowing the number of possible sets of 3 integers. They will always be between the `#([A-Z]{2}C)` and `-([0-9]{6})`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample input that shows a bit of the larger body of text AND a couple of differing substrings to capture (so that we can see the variability of your substrings) .  Please post your exact desired output given your input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
'#([A-Z]{2}C)([0-9]{3}-){1,10}([0-9]{6})#'
```

`{1,10}` specifies that the preceding subpattern enclosed in brackets `[0-9]{3}-` will repeat 1-10 times.

In addition:

If it can repeat 0 or more times for an indefinite maximum number, use `*`.

If it can repeat 1 or more times for an indefinite maximum number, use `+`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I may need to ask another question for this, but here goes: When I use your answer and print out the $matches[2] it is only printing out the last iteration of the 3 integers. I need it to print out all sets of 3 integers. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @hunter21188 You'll need to alter the capture groups a bit, try https://regex101.com/r/Tw6a7I/1/.

Comment: @chris85 Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: you could put brackets around all of it, i.e. `(([0-9]{3}-){1,10})`

Answer (score 0):

Targeting only the 3-digit substrings, individually/optionally capture the groups like this:

Pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Py0LA6/1))

```
/[A-Z]{2}C\K(\d{3}-)(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?(\d{3}-)?/
```

Comment: Down vote is not from me. I tried your method out, and it works as well. Thanks! Voted the other answer correct since it was answered first. Gave you an up vote.

Comment: It does! What I referred to in my comment was not part of the original question, but rather something additional. Adding the `?:` solved my separate question in the comment.